# Google Map API info infobox on polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use search, but answer can't find...

I have google map API, where i public polygon and marker. When click marker, he open info-window, and in this window i have same text and button. When i need to select this text, i can't because when click and move mouse, click hover is move map...

I can't enableEventPropagation: true, because i have button in window
I try z-index, but bug is not fixed
...
Please help me, live demo: http://goo.gl/b120B6

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.7324592,44.8070955),
    disableDefaultUI: true, 
};


function addMarker(id,icon,pos) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: icon
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
    map.panToWithOffset(this.getPosition(),100,-100);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/getObjectInfo',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data){
            markerData = $.parseJSON(data);
            var images = '';
            var imagespath = '/uploaded/object/photo/' + id + '/small/';
            if (markerData.files !== undefined) {
                for (var k = 0; k < markerData.files.small.length; k++) {
                    images += '<img src="' + imagespath + markerData.files.small[k] + '">';
                    if (k == 1) break;
                }
            } 

            var w_content = '<div class="info-window" id="ib">\
            <div class="title-s">'+markerData.price+' '+markerData.valuta_pref+'</div>\
            <div class="feature-area">\
                <ul class="info-feature-list">\
                    <li><span class="listtitle"><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>Area:</span> '+markerData.area+'</li>\
                </ul>\
                <button class="button moreinfo" data-id="' + id + '" style="margin-top:10px;"><i class="butoni icon-info-sign"></i> More Details</button>\
            </div>\
            <img alt="" src="assets/map_files/images/clip.png" class="clip-image">';

            var images = '';
            var imagespath = '/uploaded/object/photo/' + id + '/small/';
            if (markerData.files !== undefined) {
                for (var k = 1; k <= markerData.files.small.length; k++) {
                    images += '<div class="photo-frame'+k+'-s">\
                                    <div class="labelplace1">\
                                        <span class="label label-'+class_text_deal_type+'">Here Type</span>\
                                    </div>\
                                    <img class="photo-s" src="'+ imagespath + markerData.files.small[k-1] +'">\
                                </div>';
                    if (k == 2) break;
                }
            }
            w_content += images + '</div>';

            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.close();
            };
            infowindow = new InfoBox({
                content: w_content,
                disableAutoPan: true,
                maxWidth: 400,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-230, -296),
                closeBoxMargin: "-8px 0px 2px 2px",
                closeBoxURL: "assets/map_files/images/close.png",
                boxStyle: { 
                    opacity: 1,
                    width: "400px"
                },
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(400, 400),
                isHidden: false,
                MapPanes: "floatPane",
                enableEventPropagation: true,
                position: pos
            });
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }
    });
});
return marker;
}
```

Comment: Nice map BTW! Why exactly do you want the user to be able to select the text?  You could programatically select all the text on `click` in `infowindow`

Comment: Thx.
I have but, when i click in infobox "More Details" button, click action do it in polygon...

Comment: Can you perhaps setup a jsfiddle with basic problem?

Comment: It **is** `enableEventPropagation: true,` it should be false. Easy to reproduce -> http://jsfiddle.net/JDVWx/ - setting it to false should never inflict on the closebutton.

Comment: example -> http://jsfiddle.net/75K6V/ infobox with `enableEventPropagation: false` and clickable button.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Sorry i can't understand you :((

@davidkonrad `enableEventPropagation: true,` I can't use this option, because i have "More Details" button in window, and if i click, the button can't action, and object info not open. ((

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle.net just like @davidkonrad has done to demonstrate your problem so we can also play with the code as opposed to just staring at your demo which we can't edit!

Comment: _"I can't use this option, because i have 'More Details' button in window, and if i click, the button can't action, and object info not open._", yes you can. See my fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/75K6V. If you cant, you have a problem with the binding of the buttons click event.

Comment: Nice i do it, but now, if move cursor on infobox, hover polygon layer.. Why :(( ?